no such option: --break-system-packages
I'm using Linux Mint.
I wanted to run: pip uninstall --break-system-packages qdarkstyle
But got:
Usage:   
  pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: --break-system-packages

I was trying to search for a solution, but none of the situations described in other questions seemed to match.

The version of pip on your system doesn't have --break-system-packages.
It was added in this commit, and GitHub indicates it's available in pip 23.1 forward.
I believe that before that version, pip would happily break system packages without asking, so you should be able to just run pip uninstall qdarkstyle (here's hoping it won't break anything).
